# Understanding conditional locking

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

My challenge is this:

I want my cells in columns E - G and I-j to be automatically locked in the protected sheet. When I enter a figure into column B, figures in E - G and I - J should auto populate, though painfully some will not.

For those corresponding columns which do not auto populate, I want their locked status to be removed, based on the fact that they have no data, despite there being data in column B.

Here's another part to the trick. If data is not entered in column B but instead columns C & D, I want all the corresponding locked cells in those rows to be unlocked.

For me, communicating the logic is so much easier than doing the actual work. Fuelled by my desire to solve problems I've read it all and now I come to you, Stackoverflow, to advise me on how to proceed with all of this. I would really appreciate all the help I can get.

Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can add code snippets that you have tried.

Comment: Hi, I have not tried much as my problem is that I cannot seem to find ways to conditional lock across rows for every row in the list. The solutions seem to be isolated to individual cells :/

Comment: Some VBA functions for you to look for: `Worksheet_Change()` to check when a range is changed. `Range.Locked` for lock/unlock a Range (cell). `Worksheet.ProtectContents` to protect/un-protect a worksheet. With these, you should be able to build your logic.  Get back here if you encounter any problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to give you a generalised answer here.

1. To lock ranges on a sheet use the `Locked` property. Note that the sheet must be protected for the lock to work.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:G1").Locked = True
Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect "password"
```

2. To unlock ranges on a sheet

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:G1").Locked = False
```

3. To loop over a range

```
Set rng = Range("A1:A3")

For Each cell In rng
  ''do something
Next cell
```

4. To make your code run at the point when data is entered you need to use the `Worksheet_Change` method. It is triggered every time the sheet changes and the target is the cell value that has changed

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
    ''write the logic in this method 
End Sub
```

Put all of these together to suit your logic.